# editor Mu micropython problema para ir a la lista de archivos del dispositivo

Tags: python, embebido, micropython

Tengo este problema cuando hago clic en el boton archivos(files)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

uso la última versión de mu y estoy usando el ESP8266, ya probé con versiones anteriores de mu como alpha 1 y 2.

solo me permite cargar el firmware y despues cuando quiero ver los archivos del dispositivo no puedo y arroja la siguiente ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

comparto la informacion del registro, no se por que sigue apareciendo la version alpha cuando ya la desinstale, una disculpa por publicar en ingles, estoy un poco estresado por este problema y no tuve cuidado con el asunto, gracias

Starting Mu 1.1.0.alpha.2 2022-04-22 16:55:28,632 - root:114(run) INFO: uname_result(system='Windows', node='3D1', release='10', version='10.0.19041', machine='AMD64', processor='Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel') 2022-04-22 16:55:28,632 - root:115(run) INFO: Python path: ['C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Mu\pkgs', 'C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Mu', 'C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Mu\Python\python36.zip', 'C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Mu\Python\DLLs', 'C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Mu\Python\lib', 'C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Mu\Python', 'C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\python\mu\site-packages', 'C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Mu\pkgs\IPython\extensions'] 2022-04-22 16:55:28,633 - root:116(run) INFO: Language code: es_MX 2022-04-22 16:55:28,886 - mu.logic:587(init) INFO: Setting up editor. 2022-04-22 16:55:28,887 - mu.logic:607(init) DEBUG: Creating directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\python\mu\site-packages 2022-04-22 16:55:28,888 - mu.logic:353(get_admin_file_path) DEBUG: Creating admin file: C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\python\mu\settings.json 2022-04-22 16:55:28,889 - mu.logic:609(init) INFO: Settings path: C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\python\mu\settings.json 2022-04-22 16:55:28,890 - mu.logic:353(get_admin_file_path) DEBUG: Creating admin file: C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\python\mu\session.json 2022-04-22 16:55:28,890 - mu.logic:610(init) INFO: Session path: C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\python\mu\session.json 2022-04-22 16:55:28,891 - mu.logic:611(init) INFO: Log directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\python\mu\Logs 2022-04-22 16:55:28,891 - mu.logic:612(init) INFO: Data directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\python\mu 2022-04-22 16:55:28,938 - mu.logic:625(setup) INFO: Available modes: python, circuitpython, microbit, esp, web, debugger, pygamezero 2022-04-22 16:55:28,939 - mu.logic:629(setup) DEBUG: Creating directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\mu_code 2022-04-22 16:55:28,940 - mu.logic:637(setup) DEBUG: Creating directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\mu_code\images 2022-04-22 16:55:28,964 - mu.logic:643(setup) DEBUG: Creating directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\mu_code\fonts 2022-04-22 16:55:28,965 - mu.logic:646(setup) DEBUG: Creating directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\mu_code\sounds 2022-04-22 16:55:28,987 - mu.logic:652(setup) DEBUG: Creating directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\mu_code\music 2022-04-22 16:55:29,000 - mu.logic:658(setup) DEBUG: Creating directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\mu_code\templates 2022-04-22 16:55:29,029 - mu.logic:661(setup) DEBUG: Creating directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\mu_code\static 2022-04-22 16:55:30,233 - mu.logic:1266(change_mode) INFO: Workspace directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\mu_code 2022-04-22 16:55:30,234 - mu.logic:684(restore_session) INFO: Restoring session from: C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\python\mu\session.json 2022-04-22 16:55:30,234 - mu.logic:685(restore_session) DEBUG: {} 2022-04-22 16:55:30,234 - mu.logic:1221(select_mode) INFO: Showing available modes: ['python', 'circuitpython', 'microbit', 'esp', 'web', 'debugger', 'pygamezero'] 2022-04-22 16:55:34,572 - mu.logic:1226(select_mode) INFO: New mode selected: esp 2022-04-22 16:55:34,619 - mu.logic:1266(change_mode) INFO: Workspace directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\mu_code 2022-04-22 16:55:34,684 - mu.logic:1266(change_mode) INFO: Workspace directory: C:\Users\3DESIGN\mu_code 2022-04-22 16:55:35,731 - mu.logic:742(restore_session) INFO: Starting with blank file. 2022-04-22 16:55:52,969 - mu.modes.base:261(find_device) INFO: Found device on port: COM3 2022-04-22 16:55:52,970 - mu.modes.base:262(find_device) INFO: Serial number: 2022-04-22 16:55:52,994 - mu.modes.esp:181(toggle_files) INFO: Toggle filesystem on. 2022-04-22 16:55:54,056 - mu.modes.base:435(ls) ERROR: Could not enter raw REPL. Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Mu\pkgs\mu\modes\base.py", line 432, in ls result = tuple(microfs.ls(self.serial)) File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Mu\pkgs\mu\contrib\microfs.py", line 188, in ls ], serial) File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Mu\pkgs\mu\contrib\microfs.py", line 139, in execute raw_on(serial) File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Mu\pkgs\mu\contrib\microfs.py", line 91, in raw_on flush_to_msg(serial, raw_repl_msg) File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Mu\pkgs\mu\contrib\microfs.py", line 72, in flush_to_msg raise IOError('Could not enter raw REPL.') OSError: Could not enter raw REPL. 2022-04-22 16:55:54,104 - mu.interface.main:763(show_message) DEBUG: There was a problem getting the list of files on the device. Please check Mu's logs for technical information. Alternatively, try unplugging/plugging-in your device and/or restarting Mu. 2022-04-22 16:55:54,104 - mu.interface.main:764(show_message) DEBUG: None 2022-04-22 16:56:00,799 - mu.logic:1137(quit) DEBUG: Session: {'theme': 'day', 'mode': 'esp', 'paths': [], 'envars': [], 'minify': False, 'microbit_runtime': '', 'zoom_level': 2, 'window': {'x': 137, 'y': 77, 'w': 1092, 'h': 614}} 2022-04-22 16:56:00,799 - mu.logic:1138(quit) DEBUG: Saving session to: C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\python\mu\session.json 2022-04-22 16:56:00,800 - mu.logic:1152(quit) INFO: Quitting.

Starting Mu 1.1.1 after text su much..... 2022-04-22 17:26:43,365 - mu.modes.esp:214(toggle_files) INFO: Toggle filesystem on. 2022-04-22 17:26:45,437 - mu.modes.base:686(ls) ERROR: Could not enter raw REPL. Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\site-packages\mu\modes\base.py", line 683, in ls result = tuple(microfs.ls(self.serial)) File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\site-packages\mu\contrib\microfs.py", line 185, in ls out, err = execute(["import os", "print(os.listdir())"], serial) File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\site-packages\mu\contrib\microfs.py", line 139, in execute raw_on(serial) File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\site-packages\mu\contrib\microfs.py", line 91, in raw_on flush_to_msg(serial, raw_repl_msg) File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\site-packages\mu\contrib\microfs.py", line 72, in flush_to_msg raise IOError("Could not enter raw REPL.") OSError: Could not enter raw REPL. 2022-04-22 17:26:45,538 - mu.interface.main:1033(show_message) DEBUG: There was a problem getting the list of files on the device. Please check Mu's logs for technical information. Alternatively, try unplugging/plugging-in your device and/or restarting Mu. 2022-04-22 17:26:45,538 - mu.interface.main:1034(show_message) DEBUG: None 2022-04-22 17:26:52,072 - mu.modes.esp:218(toggle_files) INFO: Toggle filesystem off. 2022-04-22 17:26:53,324 - mu.modes.base:61(get_default_workspace) INFO: Using workspace C:\Users\3DESIGN\mu_code from settings file 2022-04-22 17:26:53,340 - mu.modes.esp:214(toggle_files) INFO: Toggle filesystem on. 2022-04-22 17:26:54,387 - mu.logic:1496(select_mode) INFO: Showing available modes: ['python', 'circuitpython', 'microbit', 'esp', 'web', 'pyboard', 'debugger', 'pygamezero', 'lego', 'pico'] 2022-04-22 17:26:55,400 - mu.modes.base:686(ls) ERROR: Could not enter raw REPL. Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\site-packages\mu\modes\base.py", line 683, in ls result = tuple(microfs.ls(self.serial)) File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\site-packages\mu\contrib\microfs.py", line 185, in ls out, err = execute(["import os", "print(os.listdir())"], serial) File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\site-packages\mu\contrib\microfs.py", line 139, in execute raw_on(serial) File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\site-packages\mu\contrib\microfs.py", line 91, in raw_on flush_to_msg(serial, raw_repl_msg) File "C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\Programs\Mu Editor\Python\lib\site-packages\mu\contrib\microfs.py", line 72, in flush_to_msg raise IOError("Could not enter raw REPL.") OSError: Could not enter raw REPL. 2022-04-22 17:26:55,407 - mu.interface.main:1033(show_message) DEBUG: There was a problem getting the list of files on the device. Please check Mu's logs for technical information. Alternatively, try unplugging/plugging-in your device and/or restarting Mu. 2022-04-22 17:26:55,408 - mu.interface.main:1034(show_message) DEBUG: None 2022-04-22 17:27:34,778 - mu.settings:169(save) DEBUG: Saving to C:\Users\3DESIGN\AppData\Local\python\mu\session.json 2022-04-22 17:27:34,789 - mu.logic:1407(quit) INFO: Quitting.

Comment: ¿Ha probado [Thonny](https://thonny.org)?

Comment: no lo conocia lo probare y estare reportando resultados, muchas gracias